# How to access the index value from NSArray

Tags: iphone, object, nsarray

I need to access the value of an NSArray by index. The following code crashes on line 3:

```
livevalues=[responseString JSONValue];
NSLog(@"%d",[livevalues count]);

NSString *objectvalue = [livevalues objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"redyyyyyyyyyyy%@",objectvalue);
```

1. `livevalues` count is 4
2. `livevalues` array string is `{"to": "INR", "rate": 53.801043700000001, "from": "USD", "v": 53.801043700000001}`

I need values from that array is only `53.801043700000001 only`

Comment: Look at your JSON - it's not an array, it's a dictionary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Dictionary so Try like below

```
NSString *objectvalue = [livevalues objectForKey:@"rate"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following expression

```
livevalues[1][@"rate"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use :

```
 NSString *objectvalue = [[livevalues objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"yourKey"];
```

to get the key for the desired string `NSLog` the description of the array and get your key from there

```
 NSLog(@"%@",[livevalues description]);
```